# How to retrieve value from bytes stored in a byte array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to store 8 bytes in a byte array to store the value of a pointer.

```
int main() {
    unsigned long a = 0;
    char buf[8];
    int i = 0;
    int *p = &i;
    a = (unsigned long)p;

    while (i < 8)
    {
        buf[i] = (a >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF;
        i++;
    }
    a = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 8)
    {
        a = ?
        i++;
    }
    p = (int *)a;
}
```

The first loop stores successive bytes of p, as casted into usigned long in a, but I don't know how to retrieve the value in the second loop. Does somebody have a clue?

Comment: The opposite of `>>` is `<<`. And the opposite of `&` is `|`.

Comment: @alk what do you mean by "opposite" ?

Comment: OT: Better use `uintptr_t` than `unsigned long` and along with this define and use `size_t ptrsize = sizeof(p)` instead of  the magic `8`.

Comment: In this context I referred to "*opposite*" as steps symmetric to the steps performed in the 1st loop, when in the second loop  doing the reversal operation to what is done in the 1st loop.

Comment: @alk If I add: `a |= buf[i]` and `a <<= 8`, which I tried before, I get different results: `a = 140724635125076` before vs `a = 18446744062955356160` after

Comment: Are you sure a `long` is 8 bytes wide on the test system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the inverse code to yours:

```
a = 0;
while (i < 8)
{
    a |= ((unsigned long)buf[i] & 0xff ) << (8 * i);
    i++;
}
```